# How to fix this C++ code with runtime error malloc: sysmalloc: Assertion

Tags: c++11, vector, stl, push-back

So the problem is that this code gives malloc error when run. The input I give is n = 2, x = 4.

I think the problem is with vector pre because this happens when push_back is called.

```
int n, x;
cin>>n>>x;
n = (1<<n);
vector<int> taken(n, 0);
vector<int> pre;
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if(!taken[i]) {
        taken[i] = 1;
        if(i^x < n)
            taken[(i^x)] = 1;
        pre.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

The error message I get is exactly this:

```
a.out: malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && 
old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse 
(old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not a compilation error.

Comment: Please provide a complete program triggering this assertion. Also, what you describe is a _runtime_ error - an assertion failure from the C library (which has malloc, which is probably used by `std::vector` under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

This line: `if (i^x < n)` is probably not doing what you want it to, since `^` has lower precedence than `<`.

You can fix that by writing `if ((i^x) < n)`